# $_REQUEST not created when using variable variables?

Tags: php

Consider the following snippets of code:

**Exhibit A:**

```
$_REQUEST = json_decode(stripslashes(json_encode($_REQUEST, JSON_HEX_APOS)), true);
```

**Exhibit B:**

```
${'_REQUEST'} = json_decode(stripslashes(json_encode(${'_REQUEST'}, JSON_HEX_APOS)), true);
```

**Exhibit C:**

```
${'_' . 'REQUEST'} = json_decode(stripslashes(json_encode(${'_' . 'REQUEST'}, JSON_HEX_APOS)), true);
```

---

Both exhibit **A** and **B** work perfectly fine, exhibit **C** however displays a very strange error message:

> Notice: Undefined variable: _REQUEST

What makes it even more weird is that this only happens with the `$_REQUEST` superglobal, if I try it with `$_GET`, `$_POST` or `$_COOKIE` all experiments work fine without raising error notices.

**I'm guessing this is a PHP bug?** I'm running on `PHP 5.3.0`.

Comment: If that is the case, it seems to me php bug too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*(I tested with PHP 5.3.1)*

One funny thing is that this portion of code :

```
<?php
var_dump(${'_' . 'REQUEST'});
```

Gets the notice `Undefined variable: _REQUEST`

But this one :

```
<?php
var_dump($_REQUEST);
var_dump(${'_' . 'REQUEST'});
```

Doesn't give any notice, and shows two empty arrays.

For a while, I though this could be related to [`auto_globals_jit`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-globals-jit), but `$_REQUEST` doesn't seem to the concerned by that directive... But there is one interested thing said, here :

> Usage of SERVER and ENV variables is
>   checked during the compile time so
>   using them through e.g. [variable
>   variables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) will not cause their
>   initialization.

Maybe, after all, even if it's not said in the manual, `auto_globals_jit` has an impact on `$_REQUEST`...

And, to be sure, I turned Off `auto_globals_jit` in my `php.ini` file :

```
; When enabled, the SERVER and ENV variables are created when they're first
; used (Just In Time) instead of when the script starts. If these variables
; are not used within a script, having this directive on will result in a
; performance gain. The PHP directives register_globals, register_long_arrays,
; and register_argc_argv must be disabled for this directive to have any affect.
; http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-globals-jit
auto_globals_jit = Off
```

And tried this code again :

```
<?php

var_dump(${'_' . 'REQUEST'});
```

And I now get an empty array, and not a notice anymore.

So it seems `auto_globals_jit` does indeed have an impact on `$_REQUEST` -- even if it's not mentionned in the manual.

Comment: Maybe it is possible that the `$_REQUEST` global is never created unless you access it directly, and concatenating the strings together doesn't trigger its creation. If so, would be really bad programming.

Comment: On that page you linked, it states that you can't use variable variables with superglobal arrays. probably caused by that line you just gave us.

Comment: @Chacha102 : I edited my post at about the same time you posted your comment, to copy-paste a note about that (and I just saw you posted another answer that quotes another section of the manual that says the same kind of thing) -- this comment arrived after your second one, but was posted before I saw it, btw ^^

Comment: kk. I just deleted mine since it seems like you've figured it out :)

Comment: @Chacha102 : your answer included the quote from the "variables variable", that was interesting too -- and which I didn't quote

Comment: @Pascal: Thanks, can you reproduce the notice with other superglobals and `auto_globals_jit = On`?

Comment: @Alix : I have exactly the same behavior (i.e notice when `auto_globals_jit=On` and no notice when `auto_globals_jit=Off`) with `SERVER` ; but not with `GET` -- I suppose this relates to the sections of the manual @Chacha102 and I quoted

Comment: @Pascal: Got it, thanks! Still it's confusing since the manual says that superglobals can't be used as variable variables...

Comment: @Alix : now that you're saying it, it's strange indeed ^^ Not sure why/how I don't get the notice with GET ; maybe GET/POST are more "magic" than SERVER :-D  (I suppose GET is always created, no matter what -- but not sure about that)

Answer (score 2):

> Please note that variable variables cannot be used with PHP's Superglobal arrays within functions or class methods. The variable $this is also a special variable that cannot be referenced dynamically.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

This is most likely related to:

> Usage of SERVER and ENV variables is checked during the compile time so using them through e.g. variable variables will not cause their initialization.

From Pascal's Answer.

Which can all be related back to the `auto_globals_jit` option.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going with the bug since $_GET etc do work
It's not been mentioned at the php bugtrack: http://bugs.php.net/

Maybe you should report it.

---

I did some quick debugging in Zend Studio:

```
<?php
var_dump( ${'_' . 'REQUEST'});
var_dump( ${'_REQUEST'});
var_dump( $_REQUEST);
```

And it seemed to work with the included PHP 5.2.10. Maybe you could use this as a workaround:

```
$foo = '_' . 'REQUEST'
$$foo //<-- is the same as $_REQUEST
```

EDIT: Woops, this wouldn't work with Superglobals, sorry -- thanks Cacha102

Answer (score 0):

Found this ["bug" report](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=34698&edit=2). According to **tony2001@php** it's not a bug:

> Variable variables: Superglobals
>   cannot be used as variable variables
>   inside functions or class methods.

[This page says the same thing](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.predefined.php), but what is weird is that this only happens with `$_REQUEST`, other GPC superglobals don't raise the error notice, **can anyone double-check this?**