# $_REQUEST superarray not initialized in $GLOBALS array

Tags: request, php, global, superglobals

## PROBLEM

So, I have this function to retrieve and proceed data from $_REQUEST, $_POST, $_GET or $_COOKIE arrays. I know which array to use only from function call. Simplified ex:

```
function gg( $name, $type="_REQUEST" ) {
    return isset( $GLOBALS[$type][$name] ) ? $GLOBALS[$type][$name] : false;
}
```

And it works perfectly for calls like:

```
gg('var', '_GET');
gg('var2', '_POST');
```

But fails dramatically for:

```
gg('var');
// or
gg('var', '_REQUEST');
```

I managed to simplify this problem thou to 2 lines:

```
print_r( $GLOBALS['_REQUEST'] ); // this line returns nothing...
print_r( $_REQUEST ); // ...UNLESS this line is present anywhere in the code
```

Now, my obvious question is: Is there any necessity to initialize this $_REQUEST array to be present in $GLOBALS?

additional info:

```
php: 5.3.3-7
apache: 2.2.16

also I'm running on CGI/FastCGI
```

## EDIT & SOLUTION

## 1

As found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2078102/request-not-created-when-using-variable-variables) the easiest solution would be to edit php.ini and change there value of [auto_globals_jit](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php) from On to Off.

```
auto_globals_jit Off
```

## 2

Instead of this you can use [ini_set()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php) inside of your source file, however it didn't work for me...

```
ini_set("auto_globals_jit", "Off");
```

## 3

Yet another solution is to use [$GLOBALS](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php) array to everything except [$_REQUEST](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php) and for $_REQUEST requests call directly to $_REQUEST array :D

```
if($type == "REQUEST") return $_REQUEST[$name];
else return ${"_".$type}[$name]; // or $GLOBALS["_".$type][$name] if previous won't work
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't replicate this on my setup so it could possibly be CGI issue? As a workaround you could do something like this...

```
function gg( $name, $type="_REQUEST" ) {
    return isset( ${$type}[$name] ) ? ${$type}[$name] : false;
}
```

Might be of interest:

> As of PHP 5.4 $GLOBALS is now initialized just-in-time. This means
>   there now is an advantage to not use the $GLOBALS variable as you can
>   avoid the overhead of initializing it. http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php

**Update.** See Post:

[$_REQUEST not created when using variable variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2078102/request-not-created-when-using-variable-variables)

Comment: Well, I already tried that... In fact it was my initial intention, but it didn't work, so I moved to $GLOBALS array :/

Comment: Yup, provided link solved the problem, I'm going to add this answer to my post

Answer (score 1):

Just a tip:

```
function gg( $name, $type="_REQUEST" ) {
  if($type=="_REQUEST")return $GLOBALS[$name];
  return isset( $GLOBALS[$type][$name] ) ? $GLOBALS[$type][$name] : false;
}
```

Once I have made a function like yours:

```
    function get_data($name)
    {
        if(isset($_GET[$name]))return $_GET[$name];
        if(isset($_POST[$name]))return $_POST[$name];
    }
```

Comment: So what you mean is it's: $GLOBALS = array_merge($_REQUEST, $GLOBALS); instead of $GLOBALS['_REQUEST'] = $REQUEST; ?

Comment: note that: "If the input arrays have the same string keys, then the later value for that key will overwrite the previous one"

Comment: Well, even if that would be the case, it would get overwritten with the same value since $_REQUEST inherits from $_GET, and $_POST and $_COOKIE are both empty... Nevertheless, your solution isn't working either, even thou it looked most promising :( .

Comment: Should be more reliable: `if($type=="_REQUEST")return $_REQUEST[$name];`

Comment: Ya, I know I fixed that during test.
edit: no wait, you changed returned array

Comment: after some test I found this page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5701588/why-is-request-empty

Answer (score 0):

$_REQUEST is already a superglobal "which means they are available in all scopes throughout a script. There is no need to do global $variable; to access them within functions or methods."

```
function gg( $name, $type="_REQUEST" ) {
  switch ($type) {
  case '_REQUEST':
    return $_REQUEST[$name];
    break;
  case 'GLOBALS':
    return $_GLOBALS[$name];
    break;
  //  etc...
  default
    return false;
}
```

Comment: You're missing the point entirely :). And I really don't want to use swich() .