# auto_globals_jit has no effect when set outside PHP.INI

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have a legacy piece of PHP code that contains $GLOBALS referring _REQUEST. Now I moved it to a new server and the code stopped working. I have found out that the problem is in setting of **auto_globals_jit** as described in this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8603953/request-superarray-not-initialized-in-globals-array).

When I changed **auto_globals_jit** in **php.ini** to **off**, it worked like a charm. Unfortunatelly, it would be better for me to limit using this setting just for the particular virtual host with the legacy application and not for the whole server. However the following setting in httpd.conf has no effect:

```
<Directory "/var/www/mydir">
  Allow from All
  Options +Indexes
  Allowoverride All
  Php_flag auto_globals_jit Off
</Directory>
```

Better said, PHPInfo() shows auto_globals_jit local value: Off, master value: On, nevertheless the code does not work.

Of course, if I put it into .htaccess, the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Run a phpinfo() to check your configuration.  It sounds like you are using php-cgi and not mod_php.  Only the latter parses the .htaccess file; the former uses the pathed in `php.ini` (and the relevant .user.ini for PHP 5.3 and later)

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately this seems to be all right. Server API: Apache 2.0 Handler, so it should be mod_php.

Comment: OK, so your <Directory> filter is not matching.  What's with the `...` you can use standard `*` and `?` but these don't span directory separators. You can also uses a PCRE compatible regexp if you prefix with `~`.

Comment: There is a normal directory, but the path was quite long, so I used ... instead. Sorry for confusion. There is simply <Directory "/var/www/mydir"> and it matches the existing directory. As I have written, everything seems ok, PHPInfo() even reports auto_globals_jit being off locally, but seems like ignoring it actually.